# Windows XP long login (15 minutes +)

Tags: domain-name-system, login, windows-xp

I'm having a lot of issues with our Windows XP SP3 machines (about five of them, but every week another gets on the bandwagon of this issue).  They take forever (15 minutes) to apply the user settings once our employees enter their username and password to log in to our domain.  It only happens say if a user has rebooted the machine and then when they go to log back in then it hangs forever.  Reboot and restart are the key words for sure I've noticed with this issue.

---

***Here are things I have tested:***

- Made sure the DNS was set to point to our two servers (Server01 & Server02 are DNS Domain Controllers, 01 is primary and 02 backup).
- No major changes have been applied to our network.
- All profiles are local, so I have deleted out local profiles that aren't being used on those machines that run slow.
- Also I have tried to enable and disable the Enable Fast Login under the local machines GP.  It was not configured originally and when I tested both, it made the computer hang on "applying computer settings" for about 15 minutes.  When it finally came up to the login screen the it was very quick to login to the domain.  However this doesn't fix my issue, and even more frustrating upon setting it back to being not configured it now still takes for forever to apply computer settings.
- I enabled the userenv log and here is what I see, but my experience is limited and I'm not sure how to read it exactly.  (see below for log, this isn't the whole thing because it's really long)

> USERENV(2ec.2f0) 10:50:41:843 LoadUserProfile: LoadUserProfileP succeeded
>
> USERENV(2ec.2f0) 10:50:41:843 LoadUserProfile:  Returning success.  Final Information follows:
>
> USERENV(2ec.2f0) 10:50:41:843 lpProfileInfo->UserName =
>
> USERENV(2ec.2f0) 10:50:41:843 lpProfileInfo->lpProfilePath = <>
>
> USERENV(2ec.2f0) 10:50:41:843 lpProfileInfo->dwFlags = 0x0
>
> USERENV(2ec.2f0) 10:50:41:843 LoadUserProfile: Returning TRUE. hProfile = <0x818>
>
> USERENV(2ec.2f0) 10:50:41:984 IsSyncForegroundPolicyRefresh: Synchronous, Reason:NonCachedCredentials
>
> USERENV(2ec.248) 10:50:41:984 IsSyncForegroundPolicyRefresh: Synchronous, 
>   Reason:NonCachedCredentials USERENV(3c4.3dc) 10:51:26:166 LibMain: Process Name:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system\wbem\wmiprvse.exe
>
> USERENV(2ec.5cc) 11:05:08:741 ProcessGPOs: network name is 192.168.49.0
>
> USERENV(4a8.888) 11:05:08:804 GetProfileType:  Profile already loaded.
>
> USERENV(4a8.888) 11:05:08:804 LoadProfileInfo:  Failed to query central profile with error 2
>
> USERENV(4a8.888) 11:05:08:804 GetProfileType: ProfileFlags is 0
>
> ---

Also this error is in the file quite a lot:

> USERENV(328.5bc) 11:05:29:733 GetUserDNSDomainName: Failed to impersonate user
>
> USERENV(328.834) 11:05:29:733 ImpersonateUser: Failed to impersonate user with 5.

---

I'm really not sure what else to do with my limited experience, but I'm hoping someone can help me.  I feel like I'm dealing with an issue way above my level and any knowledge I can gain out of getting this issue fixed would be amazing.

Comment: Ok, before you drive yourself nuts in lower level logs, what to `RSOP.msc`/`GPresult` tell you?  My experience and money says login times this long are almost certainly due to a logon script or user-level GPO calling files or network resources that can't be found, and creating long wait times because of network timeouts.

Comment: In addition, Sysinterals [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can help with additional boot logging. [Exhibit A](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx), [Exhibit B](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/07/02/3506849.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following resource, it may help:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/11/11/understanding-how-to-read-a-userenv-log-part-2.aspx

Seems to indicate that a third party security tool could be interfering. Have you changed your antivirus or firewall software?

Are any errors being reported in the Event Log? Particularly after running from the command line "gpupdate /force"?

Answer (score 1):

I would first try the registry setting known as "BufferPolicyReads".

This setting is enabled by default in Windows 7, but it has to be turned on in Windows XP.

If that is not the issue, a network packet capture with Microsoft Network Monitor would be the next step.

**Logon delays occur over a slow connection if opportunistic locking is not granted for the policy file in Windows**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319440

```
Registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon  
Entry: BufferPolicyReads  
Type: DWORD  
Value: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for network shares or devices like printers  that no longer exist or are no longer accessible.  Items in "My Network Places" can be an issue as well.  As @HopelessN00b indicates, these things create long timeouts and hence the long wait.

We had this issue with users that connected to printers and/or shares on home networks or at client sites.

Delete these items if they exist and check logon times again

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS issue. You mentioned verifying the clients were configured to use your domain controllers. Have you verified the Domain Controllers are responding to DNS queries, and that all relevant DNS records, both forward and reverse, are correct?